# Dump properties for debugging purposes

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to dump or print properties so that I can view the return inside the simulator?

For example, I have the following structure:

```
struct PlaceDetailView: View {
    let place: Place
    @State var isLiked = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            dump(place);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Generic struct 'VStack' requires that 'Place' conform to 'View'
Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Place' conform to 'View'
```

I want to be able to print out "place" and see what response I am getting back, so all help is appreciated!

Comment: `let _ = print(place)`

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx, when I attempt this, and I put it inside `var body: some View {` the simulator disappears and I get no data back, is there a something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The entire simulator disappears? Yes, something is probably going wrong. What happens with `var body: some View { let _ = print(place); Text("Hello, world") }`

Comment: For some odd reason, nothing prints out but "Hello, World", I'm able to access another property by doing `Text(place.description)` and that prints just fine, but I guess it won't print the object.

Comment: "Hello World" shouldn't `print` to the console at all... It should display in the simulator.  I think I see what you want -- you want to actually see `Place` in the `View`. It's hard to say without knowing what `Place` is, but you could try `Text("\(place)")`. You may have to conform `Place` to `CustomStringConvertible`, though.

Comment: If `Place` has a property called `name: String`, you could do `Text(place.name)`, for example -- then you wouldn't have to conform to `CustomStringConvertible`

Comment: Woo, I figured it out but thanks so much for the heads up on this method also, I was able to cast the object to a string and then print it out in the simulator.

Comment: Note that `print` is generally used as the term for the console. `Render` is probably the verb you want if you want to show it in the actual view hierarchy.